# How to avoid reloading when you have forgotten a silly detail?

Tags: civilization-6

Often when I play, I forget small details. In many cases, it is things I have thought of, but then I simply forget.

An example is when I use the diplomacy card "Diplomatic league" to get two envoys instead of one when I send my first to a city state. Then I choose a civic that will be completed in just a few turns, but when those turns has passed, I forget to switch back and then 20 turns passes before I discover my mistake, missing 40 envoy points.

Sure, I can reload 20 turns back, but that is simply not fun. It's just tedious. I could also have a text document where I write everything I need to remember, and then I check this document every turn. Feasible, but also not fun. I could accept my mistake and play on, but that is very annoying, which contradicts the sole purpose of playing the game.

For me, a good solution would be if there is a mod to modify different values in the game, such as gold, number of envoys or whatever. Simply correcting the amount of envoy points would be good enough for me. Some will call it cheating. Does not matter for me. I'm playing single player to amuse myself and no one else. Instead of tediously replaying 20 turns, I'll just do a small correction to what it would have been if I had remembered it.

In some of these situations, it would be awesome if I could set a reminder for certain events, so that I get a popup (excluding those that already exist) when I have researched machinery, built a catapult or have enough faith to buy an apostle. That would be a better alternative for most situations.

Comment: That's kind of the point of the game. You have a lot of stuff to manage and need to remember what is important and what your short- and long-term strategies are. You already get a notification when the civic is complete.

Comment: As far as "how to avoid reloading", simply accept that you did not play perfectly and made a mistake.

Comment: @OrangeDog I have no problem with accepting mistake when I have made a misjudgement. Like if I picked a certain government and then regretted that choice 20 turns later. But this thing about having to remember things is - for me - not a fun part of the challenge.